# Fastest way to write byte[] chuncks on android

Tags: android, file-io

I want to `write audio data` that comes from the microphone to a file.

I have `2 threads`: one "listen" for the audio data and send it to the second thread(the consumer) which stores it in a queue. The consumer thread constantly polls the queue and writes on the file the audioData as byte[].

`I use RandomAccessFile for the writing`. Considering that everything is syncronized in my code, `should I use some non-thread-safe class like FileChannel`?

below is some code snippets:

**Read audio data**

```
private void read(){    
    // fill the buffer with the mic input       
    readFully(buffer, 0, buffer.length);        

    // creates audioData from this buffer
    WAVData audioData = new WAVData(buffer.length);
    audioData.arrayCopy(buffer);        

    // add it to the consumer       
    mAudioWritter.add(audioData);
}
```

**Write audio data** - the consumer clas

```
public void add(WAVEntity audioEntity){
    mQueue.add(audioEntity);
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mLock.notify();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    synchronized (mLock) {

        while(!isFinalized){
            //wait if queue is empty
            while(mQueue.isEmpty()){
                try {
                    mLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            WAVEntity entity = mQueue.poll();
            if(entity != null){
                try {
                    entity.writeOnFile(file);                       
                } catch (AudioRecorderError e) {
                    // error handling
                }
            }
        }
    }

    callback.threadFinished(this);          

    // try closing this file
    try {
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean writeOnFile(RandomAccessFile fWriter) throws AudioRecorderError {
    synchronized (data) {               
        //write on the file
        try {           
            fWriter.write(data);                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AudioRecorderError error = new AudioRecorderError(e, "Data chunck was not written. See stack trace.");
            throw error;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```